# How can I include package_data without a MANIFEST.in file?

Tags: python, manifest, packaging, setuptools, setup.py

How can I include `package_data` for `sdist` without a MANIFEST.in file?

My setup.py looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='foo',
    version='2015.3',
    license='commercial',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),

    package_data={'': ['foo/bar.txt']},
)
```

Versions:

```
user@host> python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.version.__version__
'3.6'
```

I just can't get `foo/bar.txt` included.

Or is [this blog post](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/) still true?  http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/

*Over the last hour, though, I've learned that these statements are somewhere between “dangerously misleading” and “damn lies”.
This is because the primary type of Python package is a source package, and the canonical method for creating a source package is by using `setup.py sdist`. However, the data specified in package_data are not included in source distributions — they are only included in binary (`setup.py bdist`) distributions and installs (`setup.py install`).*

How can I include `package_data` for `sdist` without a MANIFEST.in file?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

**TL;DR**: The keys in the `package_data` dictionaries are  **packages**; the values are lists of globs. `''` is not a valid name for any Python package.

If you want to have `bar.txt` be installed next to the `__init__.py` of package `foo`, use

```
 package_data={'foo': ['bar.txt']}
```

---

I have the layout:

```
foo/
        __init__.py
        bar.txt
setup.py
```

Now, if `foo` is a package like above, do:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name='foo',
    version='2015.3',
    license='commercial',
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    package_data={'foo': ['bar.txt']},
)
```

And after `python setup.py sdist`, I check the contents of `dist/foo-2015.3.tar.gz`

```
% tar tfz dist/foo-2015.3.tar.gz
...
foo-2015.3/foo/bar.txt
...
```

However, if I run your `setup.py` with `package_data={'': ['foo/bar.txt']}`, I can concur that the `foo/bar.txt` will *not* be added to the source distribution, *except if the `foo-2015.3.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` already has the line for `foo/bar.txt` - in that case the file will pop up in the source distribution too*

No manifest was used; the setuptools version was `3.6` (I deliberately installed the same, old version that you were using):

```
>>> import setuptools
>>> setuptools.__version__
'3.6'
```

---

The behaviour above also works in standard `distutils`: [2.6 Installing package data](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) of the "legacy" distutils documentation; with a comment for 2.7, 3.1:

> Changed in version *[2.7, 3.1]*: All the files that match `package_data` will be added to the `MANIFEST` file *if no template is provided*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately, I just followed these instructions verbatim and `bar.txt` failed to appear in `foo-2015.3.tar.gz`. You mention deliberately using an old version of setuptools, but you don't say why. Could that explain why it's not working?

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct. Empty string `''` is a special key that applies to all packages as described in [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files):


Notice that if you list patterns in package_data under the empty string, these patterns are used to find files in every package, even ones that also have their own patterns listed.

Answer (score 21):

I had the same issue and fixed it be removing :

```
include_package_data=True
```

Comment: This fixed it for me as well.

Comment: Can somebody explain why?

Comment: The top entry here explains this: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords

Comment: @AdamErickson no it does not?

Comment: See the warning in https://jwodder.github.io/kbits/posts/pypkg-data/#including-package-data-via-setup-py-setup-cfg: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html?highlight=include_package_data#including-data-files says “The data files must be specified via the distutils’ MANIFEST.in file.”, with not enough emphasis on **must be**.