# Python - how to USE additional installed package data

Tags: python, pyqt, setup.py

I have a PyQt application which needs to show some images. I saw in:

[How can I include package_data without a MANIFEST.in file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036937/how-can-i-include-package-data-without-a-manifest-in-file)

A way to include the image files in the package installation.

It works fine in the aspect that `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypacakge/images/` now contains all the files. Unfortunately images are still not being shown by the app.

My current code addresses the images files as relative paths (i.e: `images/foo.jpeg`) which I guess is wrong. But I have no idea what is the right way to address them (unless I want to use the absolute `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypacakge/images/foo.jpeg` which I believe I don't). This seems like a common enough issue, yet I can't find any resources/answers on how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Module `pkg_resources` has support to locate a file contained in a package:

```
import pkg_resources

path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('<package name>', 'images/foo.jpeg')
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.