# installed data files location with a Python library using setuptools

Tags: python, manifest, setuptools, pypi

I am building and shipping a Python library in which I need to have a template file (xml) available to edit and write on disk later.

Let's say, I have my `template.xml` in my package directory.

I read there is two approaches:

1. Have a `MANIFEST.in` with `include mypackage/template.xml`
2. Specify in `setup.py`: `package_data={'mypackage': ['template.xml']}`

In both case, I kept the option `include_package_data=True`.

Apparently, the file is put into the egg.
I am then building my library using `sdist` distribution and releasing on `pypi` (this is done in Travis).
But apparently my file is not installed. Or at least I don't find it.

To get the file, I tried to do:

```
xml_template = pkg_resources.resource_filename('mypackage', 'template.xml')
```

leading to

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypackage/template.xml'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, removing `include_package_data=True` solved the issue.

I found the idea on this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33167220/1548052
But there is no explanation why.