# How can I make pip install package data (a config file)?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have a package called `clana` ([Github](https://github.com/MartinThoma/clana), [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/clana/)) with the following structure:

```
.
├── clana
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── config.yaml
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   └── visualize_predictions.py
├── docs/
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── tests/
└── tox.ini
```

The setup.py looks like this:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools import setup

requires_tests = [...]

install_requires = [...]


config = {
    "name": "clana",
    "version": "0.3.6",
    "author": "Martin Thoma",
    "author_email": "info@martin-thoma.de",
    "maintainer": "Martin Thoma",
    "maintainer_email": "info@martin-thoma.de",
    "packages": find_packages(),
    "entry_points": {"console_scripts": ["clana=clana.cli:entry_point"]},
    "install_requires": install_requires,
    "tests_require": requires_tests,
    "package_data": {"clana": ["clana/config.yaml"]},
    "include_package_data": True,
    "zip_safe": False,
}

setup(**config)
```

### How to check that it didn't work

#### Quick

```
python3 setup.py sdist
open dist/clana-0.3.8.tar.gz  # config.yaml is not in this file
```

#### The real check

I thought this would make sure that the `config.yaml` is in the same directory as the `cli.py` when the package is installed. But when I try this:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install clana
cd venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/clana
ls
```

I get:

```
cli.py  __init__.py  __pycache__  utils.py  visualize_predictions.py
```

The way I upload it to PyPI:

```
python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel && twine upload dist/*
```

So the `config.yaml` is missing. How can I make sure it is there?

Comment: @Erwan Yes. Just like I posted in the text above.

Comment: did you try the path `config.yaml` instead of `clana/config.yaml` ?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036937/how-can-i-include-package-data-without-a-manifest-in-file

Comment: It works with `MANIFEST.in` (thank you, Erwan!) - but I thought with the `include_package_data=True` I would not need that. Why is `include_package_data` not working?

Comment: `sdist` is mostly controlled by the files [`MANIFEST` or its template `MANIFEST.in`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest), not `setup.py`. `include_package_data=True` in `setup.py` is for `bdist_*` (`bdist_egg`, `bdist_wheel`, etc) commands.

Comment: @MartinThoma In the answer I post earlier, it seems `package_data` doens't work if `include_package_data` is true. did you try to remove `include_package_data` in your config ?

Answer (score 10):

You can add a file name `MANIFEST.in` next to `setup.py` with a list of the file you want to add, wildcard allowed (ex: `include *.yaml` or `include clana/config.yaml`) 
then the option `include_package_data=True` will activate the manifest file

Comment: This works, thank you! (+1) - I don't accept this answer (by now), because I hope that somebody knows why `include_package_data` did not work.

Answer (score 10):

In short: add `config.yaml` to `MANIFEST.in`, and set `include_package_data`. One without the other is not enough.

Basically it goes like this:

1. `MANIFEST.in` adds files to `sdist` (*source distribution*).
2. `include_package_data` adds these same files to `bdist` (*built distribution*), i.e. it extends the effect of `MANIFEST.in` to `bdist`.
3. `exclude_package_data` prevents files in `sdist` to be added to `bdist`, i.e. it filters the effect of `include_package_data`.
4. `package_data` adds files to `bdist`, i.e. it adds build artifacts (typically the products of custom build steps) to your `bdist` and has of course no effect on `sdist`.

So in your case, the file `config.yaml` is not installed, because it is not added to your `bdist` (*built distribution*). There are 2 ways to fix this depending on where the file comes from:

- either the file is a build artifact (typically it is somehow created during the `./setup.py build` phase), then you need to add it to `package_data` ;
- or the file is part of your source (typically it is in your source code repository), then you need to add it to `MANIFEST.in`, set `include_package_data`, and leave it out of `exclude_package_data` (this seems to be your case here).

***Related***:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494
- https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: @MartinThoma Did that answer the question? Anything else you would like to be clarified?

Answer (score 0):

Following from [the documentation on including data files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files), if your package has data files such as `.yaml` files, you may include them like so:

```py
setup(
    ...
    package_data={
        "": ["*.yaml"],
    },
    ...
)
```

This will allow any file in your package with the file extension `.yaml` to be included.