# How to install a Python package which is just one SO file

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I have an SO file `mymodule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` that I would like to make pip-installable.

My desired end goal is to have my installed package look like this:

```
% tree /home/.../python3.7/site-packages
/home/.../python3.7/site-packages
├── mymodule-1.0.0.dist-info
└── mymodule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

This is what I have tried so far:

```
% tree .
.
├── mymodule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

```
# setup.cfg

[options]
py_modules = mymodule

[options.package_data]
* = mymodule.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

However, when trying to `pip install .` I cannot seem to get the `.so` file to be installed into `site-packages`.

Interestingly, when there is a file named `mymodule.py` instead, `mymodule.py` gets installed in the desired location.

Comment: Interestingly, when there is a file named `mymodule.py` instead, `mymodule.py` gets installed in the desired location.

Comment: Do you have a `MANIFEST.in`? Are you able to build a _sdist_ and does it contain the `.so` file? Are you able to build a _wheel_, and does it contain the `.so` file? -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050701

Comment: I didn't have a `MANIFEST.in`, but following the advice you linked I tried and it did not include the `.so` file where I wanted it.

Comment: If you update your question to show where the `.so` file ends up being placed in the _sdist_ and in the _wheel_, then we might be able to help.