# Include files in sdist but not wheel

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils, python-wheel

I have a Python C extension that contains header files in the `include` folder.
I am currently trying to build wheels and a source distribution.
Because wheels are pre-compiled, they don't need to contain header files but the sdist does.
According to the Python docs, the following files are included in a sdist:

> 1. all Python source files implied by the py_modules and packages options
> 2. all C source files mentioned in the ext_modules or libraries options
> 3. scripts identified by the scripts option See Installing Scripts.
> 4. anything that looks like a test script: test/test*.py (currently, the Distutils don’t do anything with test scripts except include them in source distributions, but in the future there will be a standard for testing Python module distributions)
> 5. Any of the standard README files (README, README.txt, or README.rst), setup.py (or whatever you called your setup script), and setup.cfg.
> 6. all files that matches the package_data metadata. See Installing Package Data.
> 7. all files that matches the data_files metadata. See Installing Additional Files.

These files are also included in the wheels as well.
How can I add the header files to a sdist but not a wheel?

Comment: Do you use `MANIFEST.in` and/or `package_data`? Use `MANIFEST.in` for sdist and `package_data` for wheels; avoid `include_package_data` to omit files listed in `MANIFEST.in` from wheels.

Comment: I know that `package_data` is included in both wheel and sdist. Although I don't use `MANIFEST.in`, I thought that the files in `MANIFEST.in` were also included in a wheel. Is that correct?

Comment: Files in `MANIFEST.in` are included in wheels only if you use `include_package_data=True`. Otherwise they are only included in sdist.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58050701 or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54953494 -- But for C extensions, I would assume that everything is automatically handled by `ext_modules` anyway.