# Python package-data not found on CI server

Tags: python, continuous-integration, python-packaging, tox

For one [python project](https://github.com/Anaphory/lexedata), I want to ship a data file with the package.
Following [various](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/) [(and partially contradictory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036937/how-can-i-include-package-data-without-a-manifest-in-file/) [advice on the mess that is Python package data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distutils), I ended up trying different things and got it to work locally on my machine with the following setup.

My `setup.cfg` contains, among other things that shouldn't matter here,

```
[options]
include_package_data = True
```

and no `package_data` or other data related keys. My `MANIFEST.in` states

```
recursive-include lexedata clics3-network.gml.zip
```

My `setup.py` is pretty bare, essentially

```
from setuptools import setup
readline = "readline"
setup(extras_require={"formatguesser": [readline]})
```

To load the file, I use

```
pkg_resources.resource_stream("lexedata", "data/clics3-network.gml.zip")
```

I test this using tox, configured with

```
[tox]
isolated_build = True
envlist = general
[testenv]
passenv = CI
deps =
  codecov
  pytest
  pytest-cov
commands =
  pytest --doctest-modules --cov=lexedata {envsitepackagesdir}/lexedata
  pytest --cov=lexedata --cov-append test/
  codecov
```

On my local machine, when I run `pip install .`, the data file `lexedata/data/clics2-network.gml.zip` is properly deposited inside the `site-packages/lexeadata/data` directory of the corresponding virtual environment, and `tox` packages it inside `.tox/dist/lexedata-1.0.0b3.tar.gz` as well as in its venv site packages directory `.tox/general/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lexedata/data/`.

However, continuous integration using Github actions fails on all Python 3 versions I'm testing with

```
UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/work/lexedata/lexedata/.tox/general/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lexedata/data/clics3-network.gml.zip'
```

at the equivalent of that same tox venv path.

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: This was [my take on package data](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/package_data.html), if it helps. Not sure what is going on in your case. Anyway, I would recommend building the distributions (sdist and wheel) and look what is in there, if your data file is at the correct location. Between attempts, make sure to clean everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost did it right, try slightly update your MANIFEST.in to any of the following examples:

- `include src/lexedata/data/*.zip`
- `recursive-include src/* *.zip`
- `recursive-include **/data clics3-network.gml.zip`

As you can find in [docs](https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/#manifest-in-commands) `include` command defines files as paths relative to the root of the project (that's why first example starts from *src* folder)

`recursive-include` expect first argument being as dir-pattern ([glob-style](https://www.malikbrowne.com/blog/a-beginners-guide-glob-patterns)), so it is better include asterisks